# Android apk successfully exported but can not run

Tags: android, export

I have been developing a small android project with Eclipse and using the sqlite database. It has been working flawlessly in the genymotion emulator.

Now I tried to export it as apk file by right clicking the project folder > Export > Export Android Application .. etc.

There was no errors in the process and in the designated destination folder, the apk file is created. I dragged and dropped the apk file to the genymotion emulator and it works

Funny thing is, after I install the apk file in my phone, when I click the icon, it says 'Unfortunately, XXX has stopped' with a button for me to click ok.

I've tried exporting  another project the same way and it worked. Can anyone tell me what signs to look for and what I could do to check what went wrong, because checking and rechecking the Eclipse project, there are no errors at all before the apk.

Comment: Well, you could connect your phone to  Eclipse, then start the app. then you will see what happen in LogCat. Maybe some version issue. If its running at the phone when you start over Eclipse, it must be some issue with the export eg not using release key or something like that

Comment: While the emulators are nice, if you have your phone right there, hook that up instead for testing. They are much faster and you get to see actual results on your device.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. am trying to learn how top do it now. never did it before.

Answer (score 0):

Start using USB Debugging and LogCat so you can see what is the problem.

Tutorial:
http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html